# Workaround for Mavericks OSX for Java security

Tags: macos, security, remote-desktop, java

Is it possible to run a version of Java on OSX Mavericks that allows for "medium" security settings? This setting is required for my business' web-based remote access portal.

Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try add a java.policy.applet file in the jar file, with following content:

grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

and sign the applet